# Where is Fullsize Image url after upload on Picasa?

Tags: c#, image, gdata, picasa

When using this code:

```
 var service = new PicasaService("ABC");
 service.setUserCredentials("username", "Password");
 AtomEntry entry = service.Insert(uri, stream, "Image/jpeg", filename);
 var link = entry.Content.Src.ToString(); //This is normal link
```

Where is the large full size Image?

Comment: not the same my friend, i try to find this After Uploaded to picasa server but not found...

Comment: Right you get an AtomEntry instead of a PicasaEntry. Did you try casting to PicasaEntry like in the doc ? https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_dotnet#PostPhotos, then `string contentUrl = entry.Media.Content.Attributes["url"] as string;`

Comment: contentUrl = entry.Media.Content.Attributes["url"] as string;

Media tag not found my friend @@?
MediaUri found but tag Attributes not found @@?

Comment: Ok no idea then ... I was just copy-pasting from https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_dotnet#PhotosInfo

Comment: PLease help me... i confuse with this...